# Photoshop is adding a border

Tags: adobe-photoshop, graphics, border

For some reason, Photoshop seems to be adding a white border around my image. It's lighter than the background and stands out when viewing the created page. This is happening with two images, using 8 and 24bit PNG and as a GIF (with save for web).

Is there a reason?

One of the images:

[image]

How it looks on the page:

[image]

Comment: Fill it with solid color (possibly using a pencil an a steady hand), you probably have a little transparency or white there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by semi-transparent pixels around the edge. When saving set your "blue" color as matte color as a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

If this is caused by transparency around the edge, you can eliminate it using the [Flaming Pear Solidify](http://www.flamingpear.com/download.html) filter(s) (in Free Plugins), or by duplicating and merging down the layer several times (Ctrl+J then Ctrl+E).